# scroll snap points after deprication

Tags: css, scroll-snap-points

Many of the scroll snap points properties are being dropped from web standards..

e.g https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-points-x

Is the scroll snap points module being replaced with anything else that allows scroll snapping through css?

Answer (score 0):

The Scroll Snap Points module isn't going away at all.

The properties that are being dropped from implementations are just properties from the [FPWD from two and a half years ago](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-css-snappoints-1-20150326). They were replaced with a new set of properties last year that may well vanish by next year (even though the module entered CR almost exactly a year ago). This is totally normal in the development of a new CSS module.

The module just isn't ready for production use yet. But that doesn't mean it's going away. What it means is that implementations, and authors, shouldn't jump the gun when it comes to brand new CSS modules. The drafts are published solely for informative purposes.